# Convert the received NetworkStream string into an object

Tags: c#, network-programming, tcpclient, tcplistener, networkstream

I am trying to get to receiving the data from the client on the server and using the TcpListener for receiving the data I am successfully get the data from the client side. So I am receiving the data into a string, but I want to convert that data into an object using C# visual studio.
listener.Start();

```
            // Is someone trying to call us? Well answer!
            TcpClient ourTCP_Client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

            //A network stream object. We'll use this to send and receive our data, so create a buffer for it...
            NetworkStream ourStream = ourTCP_Client.GetStream();
            byte[] data = new byte[ourTCP_Client.ReceiveBufferSize];

            // read the incoming data stream - note that Read() is a blocking call...
            int bytesRead = ourStream.Read(data, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(ourTCP_Client.ReceiveBufferSize));
            // echo the data we got to the console until the newline, and delay closing our window.
            //MessageBox.Show("Received : " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytesRead));
            Console.WriteLine("Received : " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytesRead));
```

Comment: What sort of object? What format is the string in? JSON? You need to be much clearer

Answer (score 0):

authors = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytesRead);

```
            string[] multiArray = authors.Split(new Char[] { '|' });

            string stdID = multiArray[0];
            string subjID = multiArray[1];
            string ChangeNo = multiArray[2];
            string IpAddress = multiArray[3];
            string Section = multiArray[4];
            string markAttend = multiArray[5];
            string currentDate = multiArray[6];
            string currentTime = multiArray[7];

            StudentAttendance stdAtd = new StudentAttendance
            {
                Sid = stdID,
                subjectId = subjID,
                CNo = ChangeNo,
                IP = IpAddress,
                section = Section,
                mark = markAttend,
                date = currentDate,
                time = currentTime
            };
```